# Amazing Magento API. Help Me?

Tags: magento

I recently make a product import script using PHP and Mangento API. I have about 1200 items in a CSV file, when I begin to run this script, there is a so slow speed. So I decide to stop the script when there is 200 items imported through the script.

But, but, but!! When I close the script, you know, when I close the browser tab of the script. The items in the admin control panel still increase. 201-202-203! But you know, I have close the script, it should not be still runing to import the item to the database!!!

What's the problem? Anyone gets any idea?

Comment: The problem is you're not capable of breaking your problem down into a form that's technically comprehensible such that people will be able to understand it and help you.

Comment: WOW! Alan Storm! I start to learn Magento MVC through your tutorial. That's excellent! I am not good at English, maybe I can not tell my question out. Sorry. Clearly, can Magento API still running when I close the script which call it? If not, I acturally happened to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that that depends on your HTTP Server software. Once the request is sent to the server, the server will start executing your request (importing products). If the browser that sent the request is closed, does it tell the Server? Does the server check periodically that the browser is waiting for the response? If you want to have better control over starting and stopping your scripts, you should run them from the command line.